# mysql dump error

Tags: mysql

I'm having some difficulty with mysqldump.  I locked my tables and ran the following command:

`mysqldump -u user -p password databasename` using my actual password and database name.

When I run this from mysql I get a 1064 error that says there is an issue with my syntax.  I've also tried running the command from terminal (outside of mysql) and receive a 'command not found' error message.  I'm not entirely sure how I should be doing this (the explanations I've found so far have been vague).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.hts.html) is a program, it cannot be executed from the mysql console. Run it from the shell.
2. Have a look at the syntax reference.

   --user=user_name, -u user_name

   --password[=password], -p[password]

As you see there is no space between -p and password. So, your command line should be like this:

```
>shell mysqldump -u <user_name> -p<user_password> ...
```

or

```
>shell mysqldump --user=<user_name> --password=<user_password> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p[password] [databasename] > [backupfile.sql]
```

you should add the `> backupfile.sql`

the other error is believe your system doesn't recognize the `mysqldump` path and you should go directly to `bin` folder from `mysql` installation.

Comment: There should be no space between -p and your password

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the target backup file name:

```
# [mysql dir]/bin/mysqldump -u username -p password --databases databasename > /tmp/databasename.sql
```

- [MySQL Commands](http://www.pantz.org/software/mysql/mysqlcommands.html)